# How to redirect all Apache 2.4 websites to maintenance page while allowing access to specified IP addresses

Tags: apache-2.4

I have two mirrored Apache 2.4 servers behind a load balancer with about 50 websites hosted on each. I need to close them for maintenance while allowing access from several specified IP addresses. During the maintenance, the maintenance.html page should be presented to the visitors. I can't close it on the load balancer (which I initially wanted), so I need to make it through Apache configuration on both servers. Does anyone know what's the most effective and the simplest method?

I've already read many similar posts but I could not find the right answer that actually works. Many thanks!

Comment: My usual solution is to have the load balancer dispplay the maintenance page and then have the admins/testers connect directly to the webservers (via a VPN or SSH tunnel) by-passing the loadbalancers. But that doesn't really help you :-)  _-_ How is the original IP-address of the site visitors delivered to your Apache webservers, because many loadbalancers are effectively reverse proxies and the ip-adddress of the connection will then be that of the load balancer, not the visitor.

Comment: I wanted to do that the way you recommend; however, I don't think it's possible to have a custom maintenance page on my load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your load-balancer forward the original IP one way or another (ProxyProtocol, X-Forwarded-For, ..) you could do something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}      !^1\.2\.3\.4$       [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !maintenance.html   [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)                /maintenance.html   [L,R=503]
```

Replace with your IP address and real maintenance page URL

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've replaced 'RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}' with 'RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}' and it's working! However, '[L,R=503]' displays "regular" Service Unavailable page, so I put 302 instead of 503 in order to enable redirection to my maintenance .html page. Do you know how to redirect to the custom maintenance page with 503?

Comment: Also, how to apply this rewrite to a whole server? Should I put it in httpd.conf file?

Comment: You should not use a redirection, sending back the page with a 503 is a search-engine best-practice. When using redirections the readers will get 'stuck' on the maintenance page and could miss the end of the maintenance period by many hours.

Comment: as for the "whole server" it depend so much of how your server is configured ... but you should be able to put this on the httpd.conf file on each vhost yes, using an include or a macro

Comment: I agree that 503 is the best practice, but I need to display a custom page during maintenance, which your solution just won't do, it shows generic 'Service Unavailable' page.

Comment: Whole server means all virtual hosts for all the websites hosted on my load balanced web servers. I would really like to avoid to close all the websites separately.

Comment: If you get a generic page that means your loadbalancer is replacing the 503, this solution works fine displaying the "maintenance.html" page in my (LB also) setup.

You could add all rule "full time" on your vhost with a RewriteCond checking the presence of the maintenance.html and this would trigger the maintenance only when the page is added to the web-roots